# JSP, MySQL and UTF-8

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, internationalization

I am going mental, international characters that I enter via a form are not being stored exactly as entered and the data stored is not being returned as its stored in the database.

If I enter 'çanak çömlek patladı' and click save on the form I use the page displays 'çanak çömlek patladı' but the database has stored 'çanak çömlek patlad? if I revisit the page again I get '￧anak ￧�mlek patlad?'' if I click save on the form without changing anything the database stores '?anak ??mlek patlad?' and the browser displays '?anak ??mlek patlad?'

I have my MySQL Server with the following config:

```
default-collation=utf8
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
```

The database character set is utf8 and database collation is utf8_unicode_ci and the table I am using is set as the same.

The first line of my JSP file is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

The html header is as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
```

I have an EncodingFilter class compiled which is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class EncodingFilter
    implements Filter
{

    public EncodingFilter()
    {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterconfig)
        throws ServletException
    {
        filterConfig = filterconfig;
        encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletrequest, ServletResponse servletresponse, FilterChain filterchain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        servletrequest.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        filterchain.doFilter(servletrequest, servletresponse);
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
    }

    private String encoding;
    private FilterConfig filterConfig;
}
```

This class is referenced in my web.xml file as follows:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>EncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>encoding</param-name>
<param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I’ve restarted my system and therefore the Tomcat and MySQL server, checked the logs and there are no errors with any of the above configuration.

Can anyone please help, otherwise I'll have no hair left?

Comment: I have just run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%character%"; on my MySQL server and get the following results:

Variable_name    Value
character_set_client     utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database    utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results    utf8
character_set_server utf8
character_set_system utf8
character_sets_dir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\share\\charsets\\

Comment: If I try to manually enter 'çanak çömlek patladı' into the company field I get the following error:

1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xC4\xB1'' for column 'company' at row 1

Can anyone please shed light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, I ditched the previous db java class and wrote a new db function as it appeared that the previous developed class was causing a double encoding issue.

The error I was getting re the manual entering of 'çanak çömlek patladı' direct to the database related to an issue with MySQL not truly handing UTF-8 on varchar fields. As soon as I updated the field to varbinary, everything worked.

I hope this helps someone, I'm sure my hair will grow back, thank you to everyone who offered suggestions.

Comment: MySQL handles UTF-8 characters just fine in a VARCHAR field: you just need to make sure you set the character encoding of the field itself to 'utf8'. See my answer below. Your code should not be encoding anything at all -- even once, let alone twice. You should be using `PreparedStatement.setString` which should take care of everything (except for the encoding in the db field).

Comment: With regards to your comment "just fine", it is dependent on what version of MySQL you are using there is a known bug. Varchar will work for some but not all as I found in my case.

If you look through all my comments on this page you will see the I have provided evidence of all expected UTF-8 encoding, both from MySQL and JSP.

In the end I used the following to update:

sql = "UPDATE contact SET company WHERE ID="+getContactID()+"";
rs = Conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs.setString(1,company);
rs.executeUpdate();

Again, I hope this useful to someone.

Comment: I have used MySQL versions 4.1 though 5.2 and all of them have worked as expected. Perhaps my expectations are different from yours, though. If there is a known bug, please provide a reference to it. Your example JDBC code does not make any sense.

Comment: Matt, that was a great blog post: thanks for doing the research and explaining the problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Before retrieving anything from database, execute `SET NAMES UTF8` query and then all of the queries. You will then get the chars the way they look.

Comment: Just to clarify, do I add something like rs.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); to each query that requests data?

Comment: Not to each query. Just at the start of the script.

Comment: So something like this:

    Statement rs = conn.createStatement();
    rs.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
    rs.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.close();

Comment: Yeah. `Statement rs = conn.createStatement(); rs.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); rs.executeQuery(sql); /*many many other statements to fulfill your needs*/ rs.close();`

Comment: Well I am no expert in this, but I would suggest the data in mysql server to be in utf8. I did a website in 3 languages and store everything in utf8 (other conditions are same for each) and with that glorious query it retrieves data as I want :) Hopefully it will do the trick for you :)

Comment: I've just tried it but unfortunatly the query brought no results back and caused an error.

The data being stored is different from that that is being input, for example data in form is 'çanak çömlek patladı', data stored in database is 'çanak çömlek patlad?' so something is a miss at the store state.

Comment: `"SET NAMES 'UTF8'"` does not need to return anything. What error happened?

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException
 at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Doesn't seem related at all o.O Are you sure the error is being produced by query execution? Either way, try posting that part of that code.

Comment: I only added the extra line of code to one function and the page that used it rendered but with no data, as soon as I commented it out of the java class, recompiled and restarted the server, the page displayed correctly well minus the utf-8 issue.

Comment: Well I am not sure what the issue is unless you post the code :) It shouldn't return any data and you shouldn't try to get it. It is a NonQuery to be executed.

Comment: I modified the syntax, the page displays but if I save I get the following error:

java.sql.SQLException: General error,  message from server: "Incorrect string value: '\xE7anak ...' for column 'position' at row 1"

Comment: Well the only idea that I have is that you are somehow trying to retrieve data from the query I suggested you. I haven't touched Java in like 2 years so I am really not sure what the error says. Btw, `'\xE7anak ...'` does it appear as you say or is there something at these dots? Might be important. Oh and now when I look at this, I would guess the problem is somewhat different and not related to my query. It is talking about column `position`. Must be a mistake in there. And again. Showing the part of code would really help. Guessing is a bit pointless.

Comment: The error is as it is with the ... the column name is position as in job title, the data I am trying to store is 'çanak çömlek patladı' the java class that contains all database functions is quite extensive and its code I have inherited from the previous project developer.

Comment: So I assume you don't get it when the data is somewhat "normal", right? Hmm. I will comment if I have any ideas. :/

Comment: I modified the syntax as follows:

Statement rs = conn.createStatement();
String setQry = "set names utf8";
rs.executeQuery(setQry);
rs.executeQuery(sql);

The page displays with data as before, if I store normal charachters, data is stored in the database and the page refreshes with the inputted data.

If however I try and but international characters, the database does not store the data and the page refreshes with the previous content.

Comment: I have just wrote the following code to test that data submitted from the form was actually UTF-8 and I can confirm the page is sending international characters correctly, as I entered 'çanak çömlek patladı' and 'çanak çömlek patladı' was in the text file:

    <%@ page import="java.io.*"  %>
    <%
    String nameOfTextFile = "test.txt";
    try {   
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF8");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(nameOfTextFile));
        pw.println(position);
        pw.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    out.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to your database can you make sure you set "characterEncoding" as "utf8"?
Also, if you open your pages in a browser (eg. ffox) what is the character encoding that is being displayed?

I think you should try a bit of "divide et impera". It is important to learn if MYSQL is the problem or not (I suspect not). To do this you can insert the UTF String in your application and save it to the database. If this is not working we know the problem is mysql. If it works it is probably the servlet.

It wouldn't hurt to add this at the servlet level:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to say my db connection has the following parameters useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 and Firefox is displaying Character Encoding as Unicode (UTF-8).

Comment: What about your tomcat? It should be started with the following included in CATLINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: In my server.xml file I have the following:

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: @mihaisimi setting `file.encoding` does almost nothing to help this problem since all these settings have certain defaults (usually ISO-8859-1) and are set elsewhere.

Comment: Could you please highlight what might be the issue and how to resolve. I have commented quite extensively what settings have been applied throughout this page, I am happy to listen to an useful suggestions you or other hay have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check following things :

1. Your database should support multilingualism(If it's MySQL, at the time of installation itself it will ask your for this option).

Comment: It is MySQL, I just carried out a default installation, on my local instance, but the cloud instance was pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Start with http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8

Your character-holding columns in MySQL will have to be able to accept UTF-8 characters. Most MySQL defaults are for `latin1` character sets unless your DDL scripts set a character set for a column.

If you want to change a table from one encoding to another, you can do it like this:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE t CONCERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

I think you can also do this on a column-by-column basis if you really want to as well. Note that ALTER may take a looooong time on tables with a lot of data, lots of indexes, etc.

Comment: The table and database are set already set to charset utf8 and collation utf8_general_ci

Comment: I've read the article http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8 and as far as I can see I have set on Tomcat, JDBC, MySQL and JSP that needs setting. I may have missed something, but been back and forth through so many articles and still no joy.

Comment: I have just added <%=request.getCharacterEncoding() %> to my page and can confirm UTF-8 is being returned.

Comment: Also <%=response.getCharacterEncoding() %> returns utf8.

Comment: I have just wrote the following code to test that data submitted from the form was actually UTF-8 and I can confirm the page is sending international characters correctly, as I entered 'çanak çömlek patladı' and 'çanak çömlek patladı' was in the text file:

    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <% String nameOfTextFile = "test.txt"; try {
        System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF8");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(nameOfTextFile));
        pw.println(position);
        pw.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    out.println(e.getMessage());
} %>

Comment: Surely this would mean that the page is posting internationaly characters correctly and now highlights that the database for whatever reason is not accepting them or storing them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have got character encoding problems(JSP-Mysql).I wrote 
String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/deneme?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=**ISO-8859-1**";
and solved the problem. But, database's table must **UTF-8**.