# insert mathematical symbol into mysql database

Tags: mysql, jsp

I want to insert mathematical symbols like pie,alpha etc. into a Mysql database table and retrieve this data,print into a jsp page. I tried, but it's displaying question mark symbol only...

When I was searching in Google it tells change into UTF8 format. i cant get it. This is my code

```
    <%
    String  string1="π";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://           
    localhost:3306/test","root","");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into math_string values('"+string1+"')");
    String query="select * from math_string";
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next())
    {

    %>

    <%=rs.getString("String_value") %></td>

    <%   
    }

    }
```

Comment: That's a rather tricky issue, all parts of the chain (editor, server, JSP page and database) need to be aware that UTF8 is going to be used - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468625/jsp-mysql-and-utf-8 and https://blogs.oracle.com/shankar/entry/how_to_handle_utf_8 .  But do yourself a favour and *don't* write wads of Java code in JSP's, it's extremely poor practice.

Comment: Or to avoid bothering with UTF encoding, you can use the HTML entities for special characters. In this case `&pi;`